# svn log --limit seems to be delayed from recent checkin

Tags: svn

After checking in, `svn log --limit 1` does not show my most recent checkin.
If I run `svn log --limit 1 -r HEAD` I will get my most recent checkin.  Does anyone have a guess to what is going on here?  Is it a local-time / server time issue?  How would I know / resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you invoke      `svn log`  on a working copy it will show you the revisions from your **last** update, not your last commit. This is because of the concept of *mixed versions working copy*

Basically imagine this example:

1. 2 Developers (dev_a and dev_b) start to work on some code:
2. both check out same directory, same revision (say r100)
3. dev_a changes file_a.txt
4. dev_b changes file_b.txt
5. dev_a commits revision 101
6. dev_b commits revision 102

both developers workingcopies are now in mixed revisions. So `svn log` will start on revision r100 on both workingcopies because this is the last updated revision.

dev_b's workingcopy is **not** on revision 102, because he didn't update. So r101 with dev_a's changes are not in his workingcopy.

The solution is either to **update** your working copy or use `-r HEAD`